# In HTML, how to push the "body" to right, and show a menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to achieve something what you may seen while using a smartphone application.

```
BODY CONTENT (* button *)
BODY CONTENT BODY CONTENT
BODY CONTENT BODY CONTENT
BODY CONTENT BODY CONTENT
BODY CONTENT BODY CONTENT
```

when you push "button", I would like to get something like that:

```
MENU | BODY CONTENT BODY
MENU | BODY CONTENT BODY
MENU | BODY CONTENT BODY
MENU | BODY CONTENT BODY
MENU | BODY CONTENT BODY
```

so the whole body is positioned right. I tried to make body absolute, save its width, and push to right:

```
$('body').css('left', $('#menu_tablet').width()+'px').width (saveWidth + parseInt($('#menu_tablet').width()) + 'px');
```

but the `saveWidth` now contain the fixed width, not the percentage. But im sure there must be a better way

Comment: You can do it with CSS and little JQuery.I will post a fiddle in 5 min

Comment: There are LOADS of plugins that do this. Here's a jQuery one: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Comment: Well, its not to hard to do it. Take a look at [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ASLRh/) Just a little example to show how easy it can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With correct CSS you can get the desired output with less lines of JQuery .Check this fiddle:

### [Type 1 Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UcLUL/2/)

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
div{
    min-width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#menu{
    display:none;
}
b{
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('b').click(function(){
    $('#menu').toggle();
});
```

### [Updated fiddle which work exactly as asked](http://jsfiddle.net/UcLUL/4/)

---

I was just thinking about facebook android version of site while writing the above fiddle.In that on menu icon click the menu shifts the body to the right and the content part is chopped off.

So if your requirement is not to chop-off the content on button click then you can try the below fiddle:

### [Type 2 demo with code](http://jsfiddle.net/UcLUL/5/) / [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/UcLUL/5/show/)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the `body` tag for this. Use containers instead:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="toggle">Toggle Menu</button>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <p>Some content goes here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Set the menu to width: 0, overflow: hidden so that it is initially collapsed */
#menu {
    width: 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* To show the menu, give it an explicit width */
#menu.show {
    width: 300px;
}
/* Make sure the content sits to the right of the menu (given enough space) */
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
/* Permanent button in the top right of the page */
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
// On click of the button, toggle the show class
$("button").click(function() {
   $("#menu").toggleClass("show"); 
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6afp/) of the above. You'll obviously need to adjust the layout and styling to meet your requirements, but this should get you on the right track.

The reason I used `width` above, is so that you can animate the width property to give you a sliding effect:

```
$("#menu").animate({ width: 300 }, "slow");
```

Comment: Graham in your Fiddle the content is shifting down instead of to the right

Comment: @Zword Depends on your screen size, I just picked some random values :)

Comment: yes, it just pushes it down :S I cant see the implementation of pushing it right

Comment: @JohnSmith Mine pushes the content down, Zword's chops off the end of your content and doesn't wrap. These aren't *complete solutions*, they are an indication if what you need to do

Comment: @JohnSmith i added a new fiddle in which you can see the side content even if it exceeds the width by scrolling. Now Graham i think my new added fiddle could be the correct and complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
```

80% - from left

example, not my, i found it http://jsfiddle.net/vishl/wzPSF/